# Is it possible to silence the Windows 8.1 alarms app?

Tags: windows-8.1, alarm

The Windows 8.1 Alarms app is pretty cool, but I noticed that when the alarm goes off, a sound is played. This occurs even though I have muted my speakers and turned sounds completely off in the Personalize section of Control Panel. Opening up the charms in the app does not show a "settings" section like most other apps do.

Is it possible to completely silence the alarms app?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and is wondering the same thing!!

The only possible solution that I have come up with is to disable the playback device on the computer.

You can then manually activate the playback device if you need to use any sound temporary on the computer.

Just remember to disable it again.

Comment: I think that OP is smart enough to physically shutdown the speakers OR to disable the device (in Device Manager) = same thing! I don't find your answer helpful sorry...

Comment: This is definitely a solution, but not the most elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

You can just turn off the "Play notification sounds".
Go to "PC Settings"-->"Search and apps"-->"Notifications"
Then change "Play notification sounds" to OFF.